# Is it possible to make a gradient header in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image: A header that act as a navigator, with a gradient background]
I searched a lot, but found nothing. **Is it possible to make an AppBar like this one ?**

### Edit

Here is a link of the full figma app: [Click Here](https://www.figma.com/file/iSBIuYxnCUsQL5BXC9mrxD/Prayer-Time?node-id=14%3A66)

Comment: Does this answer your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I made a component called `header` and put 2 button and one text to get the effect

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can pass a gradient to an AppBar as it expects a Color rather than a gradient.

You can, however, create your own widget that mimics an AppBar except by using a gradient.
Take a look at this example that I've pieced together from the [Planets-Flutter tutorial](https://sergiandreplace.com/planets-flutter-from-design-to-app/) along with the code below it.

[image]

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children : <Widget>[GradientAppBar("Custom Gradient App Bar"), Container()],);
  }
}


class GradientAppBar extends StatelessWidget {

  final String title;
  final double barHeight = 50.0;

  GradientAppBar(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double statusbarHeight = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .padding
        .top;

    return new Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusbarHeight),
      height: statusbarHeight + barHeight,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
            begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
            end: const FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
            stops: [0.0, 1.0],
            tileMode: TileMode.clamp
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this is not the expected result. If you look the image that I put, we can see the header is not at the top and this is the effect i tried to achieve

Comment: Hi, I think the solution is to **make a button like component called `header` and put it to the top so I can get both the gradiant and the button to navigate to settings/home**